# Why does this log [object Object], [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I have this Api call, which returns my `contact` list, and is supposed to save them as an array of objects into `this.state.contacts`, so that I can of course reference them in other places.

The line that says `console.log(result)` logs exactly what I expect... which is an array of objects containing all of my contact list data.

But after that, the `console.log(Contacts: ${this.state.contacts}` logs instead of the same data in `result`:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[obj
```

```
class Database extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                clients: [],
                contacts: []
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch(API_URL + `/contacts/all`)
                .then(res => {
                     if (!res.ok) {
                         throw new Error();
                       }
                       return res.json();
                      })
                        .then((result) => {
                            this.setState({ contacts: result });
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(`Contacts: ${this.state.contacts}`);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                );
        }
```

What am I missing here? I feel like I've done it like this before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is type coercion in your expression. Try to output this: `console.log('Contacts: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.contacts)}');` so your object wont be called by ToString but rather JSON.stringify will work first.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are asking JS to turn your object (`this.state.contacts`) into a string. Some options:

```
console.log(`Contacts: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.contacts)}`);
console.log(`Contacts: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.contacts, true, 2)}`); // pretty-reprinted JSON
console.log('Contacts:', this.state.contacts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(object)` to change it to a string before you use `console.log`.